# balancing two input number fields but not showing values in fields in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!--js-->
 function changeValue(dropdown,source) {
 var option = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
if (option == '1' && source==0) {



    var total = 20;
$("span").text(total);
$('.balance').attr({"min":0, "max":total}).on('input', function() {
  var value = parseInt(this.value);
  var otherInputs = $('.balance').not(this);
  var remainderDiv;
  var remainder, sum;
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    value = 0;
  } else if (value > total) {
    value = total;
  } else if (value < 0) {
    value = 0;
  }
  this.value = value;
  remainder = total - value;
  remainderDiv = remainder / otherInputs.length;
  sum = value;
  $.each(otherInputs, function(input) {
    sum += Number(otherInputs[input].value);
  });
  if (sum > total) {
    otherInputs.val(remainderDiv);
  }
});
}

    else if (option == '2' && source==0) {

      var total = 20;
$("span").text(total);
$('.balance').attr({"min":0, "max":total}).on('input', function() {
  var value = parseInt(this.value);
  var otherInputs = $('.balance').not(this);
  var remainderDiv;
  var remainder, sum;
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    value = 0;
  } else if (value > total) {
    value = total;
  } else if (value < 0) {
    value = 0;
  }
  this.value = value;
  remainder = total - value;
  remainderDiv = remainder / otherInputs.length;
  sum = value;
  $.each(otherInputs, function(input) {
    sum += Number(otherInputs[input].value);
  });
  if (sum > total) {
    otherInputs.val(remainderDiv);
  }
});

    }


<!--html-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="changeValue(this,0)">
 <option value="1">1-person</option>
 <option value="2">2-10 group</option>
</select>


<input type="number" class="balance">
<input type="number" class="balance">

<!--html-->
```

how would you do it that the remainder doesn't go in the input field two. but it should still minus from each other though when the user puts in a value. so if max =10. when the user inputs 5 in field one and puts zero in field two that would be correct. But if he puts 5 in field one and 6 in field two that would be incorrect. how could i do that using this code.

Comment: so add the two numbers and check if greater than 10

Comment: can you do a jsfiddler using my above code please

Comment: If there is only one correct value, why would you ask the user to type it? Sounds user-unfriendly to me (unless it is an addition training program for kids).

Comment: can you read the info i placed at the bottom on what i want it to do exactly

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8sdahgx7/5/)?

Comment: @tewathia this is working great. having another problem i am using it on a select dropdown the first code works when i select an option it changes the value but with the updated code it stills remain on the previous option. seems like the memory is not flushing the previous select option. UPDATED THE CODE SO CHECK WHAT I HAVE AND WHAT I WANT TO DO

Comment: @Lee See if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8sdahgx7/11/) works

Comment: @tewathia can you do it using the if statement i have i want to pass the source also its very important that i do so.

Comment: You can simply wrap the contents of the `recalculateOnChange` function inside an `if (source==0)` if that is going to be the only value of source. In case there are multiple values, you will have to list down the various if/else scenarios

Comment: ok i am going to try and see if i can do it now

Comment: @tewathia not getting it to work!!

Comment: @Lee how about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8sdahgx7/14/)?

Comment: @tewathia i modified my code using the first code you posted in jsfiddler, that's the way i want it to stay with the options and if statements. The reason i want it that way is because the fields are dynamically added. So if you could just add a function to that existing code to let it change the value when i change the select option that would be great. THE CODE UP TOP IS WORKING PERFECT IT JUST NEEDS WHAT I AM ASKING.

Comment: thanks working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Using a dropdown to control the global `MAX` variable:

```js
var MAX = 1;

function changeMax(dropdown) {
  switch (dropdown.selectedIndex) {
    case 0:
      MAX = 1;
      break;
    case 1:
      MAX = 10;
      break;
  }
}

$('.balance').on('input', function() {
  var inputs       = $(".balance");
  var currentInput = $(this);
  var otherInput   = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (!$(inputs[i]).is($(this))) {
      otherInput = $(inputs[i]);
    }
  }
  var currentValue = parseInt(currentInput.val(), 10);
  var otherValue   = parseInt(otherInput.val(), 10);
  if (isNaN(otherValue)) {
    otherValue = 0;
  }
  // disable entering "0000.."
  if (isNaN(currentValue)) {
    currentValue = 0;
    currentInput.val(0);
  }
  // disable entering negative values
  if (currentValue < 0) {
    currentValue = 0;
    currentInput.val(0);
  }
  var sum = currentValue + otherValue;
  if (sum > MAX) {
    var offset = sum - MAX;
    currentInput.val(currentValue - offset);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="changeMax(this)">
  <option value="1">1-person</option>
  <option value="2">2-10 group</option>
</select>


<input type="number" class="balance">
<input type="number" class="balance">
```

---

I tried to keep it as simple as it can be.

`MAX` is set to `10`. If you enter `2` on the first input, you can enter `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` on the other input. You can also enter negative values. If you don't want to, simply uncomment the commented part.

```js
var MAX = 10;

$('.balance').on('input', function() {
  var inputs       = $(".balance");
  var currentInput = $(this);
  var otherInput   = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (!$(inputs[i]).is($(this))) {
      otherInput = $(inputs[i]);
    }
  }
  var currentValue = parseInt(currentInput.val(), 10);
  var otherValue   = parseInt(otherInput.val(), 10);
  if (isNaN(otherValue)) {
    otherValue = 0;
  }
  /* if (currentValue < 0) {
   currentValue = 0;
    currentInput.val(0);
  } */
  var sum = currentValue + otherValue;
  if (sum > MAX) {
    var offset = sum - MAX;
    currentInput.val(currentValue - offset);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="balance">
<input type="number" class="balance">
```

Comment: this is working great.  having another problem i am using it on a select dropdown the first code works when i select an option it changes the value but with the updated code it stills remain on the previous option. seems like the memory is not flushing the previous select option.

Comment: @Lee Can you add that code with the select too? It'd be better if I just see the HTML & JS.

Comment: NO PLEASE DONT CHANGE THE VALUE OF THE SELECT OPTION TO 10 LET IT STAY AS 1 AND 2 BECAUSE I AM PASSING THE VALUE TO A DATABASE SO IT HAS TO STAY AS IS.

Comment: @Lee Lol, calm down. Check it again.

Comment: @Lee Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem :)

Comment: can you use the if statement instead of the case because its not working with the source.

Comment: `source` that's in the code you've provided does essentially nothing (in this example). Also your code has missing two `}`. One for the first `if`, and one for the `changeValue()`. What you should do is refactor your code and implement the solution I've provided. If you still encounter problems, you should post other questions.

Comment: the source is important because i am using an array to generate dynamic fields.